# Adding objects of a derived type at runtime in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, game-engine

I basically want to add a user defined class object at runtime.

Say I have a class

```
class Foo{
    virtual void init();
    virtual void update(float dt);
};
```

and another class which is added later by the user

```
class Bar : public Foo{
    void init() override;
    void update(float dt) override;
};
```

I want to have a text file which gives the name of the class as say

```
[Foo] : "Bar"
```

Now at runtime i want to query for all derived classes of Foo and instantiate an object of type Bar. How to accomplish this?

I tried creating a factory which registers the type_info at runtime but i don't think there is a way to create objects when I have their type_info.

I know that C++ doesn't support reflections.

PS: Basically I am trying to add a scripting system to a basic game engine without the hassle of creating dlls. Any other type of solutions are also welcome. You can check the project at https://github.com/Dr-42/Nomu_Engine and suggest any alternative ways.

Comment: You'll need a mechanism by which derived classes can register themselves by text text name identifier with the factory facility.  Probably along with the registration will need to have a Make function for that particular derived class, and the general Foo factory will dispatch to the appropriate derived class's Make function.

Comment: You have to write the code to associate a name with a function that creates the object. `if (name == "Bar") return new Bar();` etc. as a naive example.

Comment: `std::make_unique<Bar, CtorArgs...>` is a convenient factory function to wrap a specific constructor. And for the mapping from string to factory function you can use a `std::map`.  But yes, you'll have to initialize that mapping somehow.

Comment: I want to avoid manually mapping each class. It is supposed to be a user defined thing and the user shouldn't have to tinker with the original source. The user just adds the entry to the text file and creates a new class and the program should create the map.

Comment: Adding a class at runtime may be hugely hard to do. You may have to auto-generate some C++ code, invoke a compiler from C++ and then perhaps load the resulting library with a new subclass of an interface [using `dlopen()`](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/C++-dlopen/). But I wouldn’t bet on such an approach getting all RTTI-related things right. At the end of the day it may be better to define the interface in terms of an RPC IDL, build the dynamic implementation(s) as separate binaries, `fork()` and `execve()` them and talk to them using RPCs.

Comment: It's even impossible, all classes declaration (and definition) must be compiled in order to be available at runtime. You can't add a new class declaration (and definition) on the fly at runtime (C++ is not a reflexive language).

Comment: The definition of `Bar` looks like C++ code, and it is not complete because it lacks definitions of `Bar::init` and `Bar::update`. Do you want to replace all of this by a single line in a text file? I don't see how to accomplish this even in principle. Where should the definitions of `Bar::init` and `Bar::update` come from? Alternatively, do you want the user to write some C++ code (not modify existing code) and add new code to the running system? This is very possible, just compile it and load it as a shared library/DLL.